# Why is user mode thread handling not acceptable on a multi-core computer?

Tags: operating-system

It is my understanding that threads in user mode are often cheaper to execute and don't require system calls. Why would it not be acceptable on a multi-core machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads don't require system calls, but that doesn't mean that they can't make system calls.

> *There are two fundamental problems with implementing threads in a user mode library:*
>
> - *what happens when a system call blocks*
>
> *If a user-mode thread issues a system call that blocks (e.g. open or read), the process is blocked until that operation completes. This
>   means that when a thread blocks, all threads (within that process)
>   stop executing. Since the threads were implemented in user-mode, the
>   operating system has no knowledge of them, and cannot know that other
>   threads (in that process) might still be runnable.*
>
> - *exploiting multi-processors*
>
> *If the CPU has multiple execution cores, the operating system can schedule processes on each to run in parallel. But if the operating
>   system is not aware that a process is comprised of multiple threads,
>   those threads cannot execute in parallel on the available cores.*
>
> *Both of these problems are solved if threads are implemented by the operating system rather than by a user-mode thread library.*

Taken from [here](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/winter17/cs111/readings/user_threads.html).